# Stanford CoreNLP lemmatization

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I have written code in java that displays what each of the annotators output such as tokens, pos, semantics, ner but cant figure out how to display lemma is this possible?

So my question is, is it possible to produce a lemma output of what it is doing (the result)?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? What have you tried? (please answer by editing the question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CoreLabel` class has a `lemma()` method that returns the lemma. e.g.

```
// token is a CoreLable instance
String lemma = token.lemma();
```